# Where is master view bound to master page of a splitt app in master-detail template?

Tags: sapui5

Definition of a split app in App.view.xml looks very simple:

```
<SplitApp id="idAppControl" />
```

It doesn't define initialMaster, however, Master.view.xml is used as a default master page. Where is it stated?

Comment: SplittApp floorpaln for master detail is outdated! The new floorplan for this scenario is the FlexibleColumnLayout, please consider using that before continueing: https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/flexible-column-layout/

Comment: @Erch thank you, I've looked through this sample and still I have the same question. As far as I understand, routing for FlexibleColumnLayout is defined in routing config in manifest.json. But again, what if I want to have two FlexibleColumnLayouts in the app? I can define only one routing config for app, so is having several FlexibleColumnLayouts  possible at all?

Comment: why would you need multiple FlexColumnLayouts? you can have 4 or even more columns....

Comment: @Erch because I have two unrelated lists. I wanted to show them in two different tabs

Comment: you still have one FlexColumnLayout, you just have multiple routes for the mid column und right column, so you can have diffrent pages in those columns depending on which list you press

Comment: @Erch the problem is that I have different routes for the left column as well:) let's say, one FlexibleColumnLayout displays info about clients, and the other one - about products.

Comment: i fear you are mixing up layouts at this point. The master page should be the initial page of your app. And even if your detail pages differ depending on actions that would not change. To clarify what you intend to achieve please create an example on jsbin or an other similar page.

Comment: @Erch yes, I understand. I just wanted to have like two master-detail apps in one app each at one of two tabs of a general main page.

Comment: As i said please create an example on jsbin or even try to draw the layout in a mockup to make shure we do not mean diffrent things.

Answer (score 1):

By default it all is stated in the `manifest.json` file of your project - it resides in the root folder. In that file see node `sap.ui5/routing/routes`, there should be a route with pattern `""`, which must be your starting route. Then the route has a target in its definition, and the target contains view name (see node `sap.ui5/routing/targets`).

For more details go through [Routing and Navigation](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/#/topic/3d18f20bd2294228acb6910d8e8a5fb5)
 documentation.

Comment: if it's loaded by default, why is Master view displayed as master page only for the first split app when I have two of them in the root page?

Comment: It's a bit more complicated scenario: you have to define the root app as instance of sap.m.App which is a navigation container, then define an intermittent view with SplitContainer, define a target in manifest, then mention this new target as a parent for your master and detail targets. See more [here](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0ce0b8c56fa74dd897fffda8407e8272/7.5.12/en-US/b01840ec42ef48e6bfd2bc12612f501f.html)